# Oracle SQL query process between states time

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i have this table in Oracle:

```
Process| State | Date ;
 A| 0 | 19/09/14 ;
 A| 1 | 30/09/14 ;
 A| 2 | 31/09/14
```

With the date column you know when the process has changed to the corresponding state

I need to obtain a table like this

```
Process | Time between state 0 and 1 | time between state 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the `PROCESS`, `CHANGE IN STATE` and `NUMBER OF DAYS` :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'A' PROCESS, 0 STATE, TO_DATE('19/09/14','dd/mm/rr') DT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'A',         1,       TO_DATE('30/09/14','dd/mm/rr')    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'A',         2,       TO_DATE('01/10/14','dd/mm/rr')    FROM DUAL)
  5  SELECT PROCESS,
  6    state
  7    ||' - '
  8    ||new_state change_in_state,
  9    NEW_DT-dt NUMBER_OF_DAYS
 10  FROM
 11    (SELECT A.*,
 12      LEAD(STATE) OVER(ORDER BY STATE, DT) NEW_STATe,
 13      LEAD(DT) OVER(ORDER BY STATE, DT) NEW_DT
 14    FROM DATA A
 15    )
 16  WHERE NEW_DT-dt IS NOT NULL
 17  /

PROCESS    CHANGE_IN_ NUMBER_OF_DAYS
---------- ---------- --------------
A          0 - 1              11
A          1 - 2               1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the process must progress through state 0, will have 1 as next state, and 2 as next state; this query uses LEAD() to look ahead 1 and 2 state values (if these exist)

**Query**

```
SELECT
       PROCESS
     , l1STATEDATE - STATEDATE   AS TIME_0_1
     , l2STATEDATE - L1STATEDATE AS TIME_1_2
FROM (

      SELECT
              PROCESS
            , STATE
            , STATEDATE
            --, lead(STATE,1)     over(partition by PROCESS ORDER BY STATEDATE) as l1STATE
            , lead(STATEDATE,1) over(partition by PROCESS ORDER BY STATEDATE) as l1STATEDATE
            --, lead(STATE,2)     over(partition by PROCESS ORDER BY STATEDATE) as l2STATE
            , lead(STATEDATE,2) over(partition by PROCESS ORDER BY STATEDATE) as l2STATEDATE
      FROM STATEINFO
     )
WHERE STATE = 0
```

**Result:**

```
| PROCESS | TIME_0_1 | TIME_1_2 |
|---------|----------|----------|
|       A |       11 |        1 |
```

<kbd>[See the SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55544/2)</kbd>

---

Note I used a field name "stateDate" as I don't recommend using SQL keywords as names

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I obtain the time_0_1 with 0 vlaue, and the rest is null. I dont know why

Comment: is your actual data like the small sample? what are the real field names and table name? The more effort you put into the sample the better the result. You could also setup your own http://sqlfiddle.com and provide us the URL

Comment: I got it, U_B_A. Thanks a lot!